# How to export large pandas Data Frame to excel format?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, binary

I have converted binary files to NumPy array and then pandas data frame. The final shape is 217 rows × 524289 columns.

When I tried to save it as .xlsx format:

```
dft.to_excel('dft.xlsx')
```

the below error appeared:

```
ValueError: This sheet is too large! Your sheet size is: 217, 524289 Max sheet size is: 1048576, 16384
```

I would really appreciate your responses.

Comment: export to csv format should work.

Answer (score 0):

Either save as .csv, or split it into 4 dataframes before saving it as .xlsx. From the error you see that the max amount of columns is 16384, so splitting into 4 smaller dataframes would work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comment and reply.
I found a trivial solution and want to share it with you. As I tried to save it only as .xlsx (not csv), I realized it could be saved by changing the rows with columns (transpose).